# Need to make my tool work automatically without any button

Tags: c#

I have one window's application in c# which generates mail by retrieving the data from the database on a button click and generate mails in outlook.

Now, I need to make my application to work automatically therefore, on every Monday it will start sending the mail by itself.

Please suggest me some idea and code which can resolve my issue.

Comment: Create a Console application and use Task Scheduler to run it on every monday.

Comment: You can create a windows task that starts te application, or a windows service that runs once a week, or train a monkey to press the button each monday. The problem with the last option is that it needs food...

Comment: is there any code available on you for that console application as I need to do this on urgent basis.

Comment: I can't use windows task scheduler as it creates the reliability issue please suggest something else

Comment: A c# console application would have nearly all the same code you have now in your c# (winforms?) application. Please google or read the docs or anything....

Comment: You would need to do it via a scheduler oid. especially if you're only going to do it each monday. Are you going to keep it running untill then?

Comment: @ManishPrajapat Reliability issue? Can you elaborate? I disagree, task scheduling works very well in this kind of scenario.

Comment: we will get the fresh data on Saturday. so, we need to run it from Monday to Friday.

Comment: reliability means If I use task scheduler it totally depend on my system and I don't want that this application will only run from my system because if any worst scenario my system goes crash then this will create the issue.

Comment: @ManishPrajapat That is what servers are for. Tasks are not ment to be run on the developers machine. Servers on the other hand are supposed to be on at all times. This is not a reliability issue at all.

Comment: set a timer which interval is 24 hours. Let it check if day is monday then send mail.

Answer (score 2):

Change the application to accept a command line argument to make it send the email when the application starts and shut down after. Then create a windows "scheduled task" to launch the app with the correct commandline argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make  Window Service and schedule it.

Basically you can put your code call on button click in a Console Program (output will be an .exe) and then schedule it with windows scheduler every Monday.

Hope it help you !